# Duplicate value fields when creating relationships field collection of views

Tags: views, entities

I have a problem need help. I created one field collection (unlimited value) for content type. Then I create 1 views to ren value fields in tables. I created relationship field collection for the that views and have a problem that the fields of the node duplicate value by the number of the field collection values. How can I remove duplicate of the field value in that content type.
[image]

Answer (score 1):

on right hand **others** >> **query settings** of you view there is one distinct checkbox enable it. Which will distinct your result

Comment: It not working.

Answer (score 1):

You can apply `group by` or `distinct` by enabling views aggregation settings to remove duplicate records.

1- in advanced » other section by enabling `use aggregation`: yes
2- in `fields` or filter criteria section, select and apply aggregation settings for which fields you want to group by or distinct.

Comment: It not working for field collection relationship

Answer (score 0):

This worked for me i had movies and cast list so when i enabled the aggregation field all the actors of a movie in cast list were separated in different rows. 
In the Aggregation settings of the field(cast list) , choose **aggregation type: group results together**( which is by default) and **group column : entity ID**( by default it was target id) and your duplicates should be removed.